# How can I invoke onInit() each time I go to a view?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, reload

I have two views: Login and Menu.

Scenario:

> Log in --> `onInit() , onBeforeRendering() , onAfterRendering()` gets
>   called in Menu.controller.js and go to the Menu view.
>
> Log out --> `deleteData(); oRouter.navTo("Login", {}, true);` Back to
>   the login view.
>
> Log in --> `onInit() , onBeforeRendering() , onAfterRendering()`
>   doesn't get called and go to the Menu view.

I've tried to attach my Menu controller to a specific route in onInit but it doesn't work:

```
function onInit(){
    this._oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    this._oRouter.attachRouteMatched(initMenu, this);
    this.initMenu();
}
```

**How to forcefully call the above methods again? I need to reload the method `initMenu()` which is in the onInit() function to receive the menu correctly.**

Answer (score 2):

onInit is called one time only. Its life cycle method of Sapui5. If you want  a function which will get called every time you navigate then use onAfterRendering or onBeforeRendering. Other wise create function and call that function from route match.

> above route match should be like this.

```
this._oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
 this._oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.yurfunction, this);
```

//now do as below

```
yurfunction(){ //now give call to you function from here }
```

Comment: I've tried both things but they don't work. If I call that function from route match it's also run when I log out. If I use onAfterRendering or onBeforeRendering nothing happens because the page doesn't rerender.

Comment: well that is only what problem with route match create one global variable and assign make it true once function is executed make that global variable false. sap.ui.getCore().urVariable=true;do this in onInit. Now if(sap.ui.getCore().urVariable){// you stuff.sap.ui.getCore().urVariable=false; } set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into onBeforeShow() method of a view. This lifecycle hook will be called everytime a view is displayed. You can do your operations here. See : https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainerChild.html